# I would like to change an imported function in python without changing the source file

Tags: python, function, import, hook, decorator

I would like to change an imported function in python but have literally no clue where to start or how to do this.. I have seen decorators and hooks before, but not sure if this is the correct way to approach the problem

Basically the function that I want to change is the following:

```
def load_coco_json(json_file, image_root, dataset_name=None, extra_annotation_keys=None):
```

This function does a whole lot of things, but the thing I am interested in is

```
img_ids = sorted(coco_api.imgs.keys())
```

I would like to add some kind of decorator to accomplish the following:

```
img_ids = sorted(coco_api.imgs.keys())
img_ids = img_ids[0:20]
```

Basically, from my processing notebook, I want to be able to define how many img_ids are used in this load_coco_json function. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please fully show the function `load_coco_json`?

Comment: You cannot really **change** a function, but **replace** it with another one and call the original function if desired from within the new function, that you wrote.

This is called monkey patching.

Would this help?

Comment: @Dmitry Shevchenko I'd rather not post the complete source code here as it is much too lengthy: https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/detectron2/data/datasets/coco.html#load_coco_json

Comment: @gelonida I am not sure if this would help, as it is a mess of different classes and functions intertwining with each other, I have to make sure the replaced one is called.. I would have to add a cell with a huge amount of code and change 1 line in there? I was hoping there is a more elegant and short solution that is easy to alter in case required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke so basically, I monkey patched it.

Copied the entire function from load_coco_json:

```
def load_coco_json(json_file, image_root, dataset_name=None, extra_annotation_keys=None):
    imgs = coco_api.loadImgs(img_ids)
```

Then I renamed it and applied the patch

```
def monkey(json_file, image_root, dataset_name=None, extra_annotation_keys=None):
    imgs = coco_api.loadImgs(img_ids)
    imgs = imgs[0:10]
```

Then I changed the function as follows:

```
detectron2.data.datasets.coco.load_coco_json = monkey
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you will not be able to pull intermediate values from the function. All I can advise is to write your own function that will return what you need. Here is an example, it may need to be improved:

```
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
import contextlib
from detectron2.utils.file_io import PathManager
import io


def my_func(json_file):
    json_file = PathManager.get_local_path(json_file)
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()):
        coco_api = COCO(json_file)
        img_ids = sorted(coco_api.imgs.keys())
        return img_ids
```

Comment: Thank you, how would this turn out in practice? You defined a function that returns the img_ids from the json file, which works fine as expected! However, load_coco_json is running in the background when I call another function named register_coco_instances. How to let load_coco_json know it has to use my_func to define img_ids and not what is defined within load_coco_json?

Comment: This approach is not entirely correct, because you have functions that do what they should. You want to call these functions to do something different. You need to either write your own functions that will return what you want, or create many monkey patches, for example, override the `load_coco_json` function before calling the `register_coco_instances` function.

Comment: I have written a monkey patch. Writing my own functions would be very messy as this specific function does much more than what I want to change..